# Metaprogramming multi-level method_missing

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I would like to be able to have a dynamic proxy for two levels of ghost methods in a module. I'm assuming the first level needs to dynamically create a module with a variable that keeps track of the name of my 1st level call, and a method missing to accept my 2nd level call, but I'm at a loss on how to turn this into working code.

```
module Test
    def self.method_missing(name, *args)
        #dynamically create a module and return it
        #so my 2nd level call hits its method_missing
    end
end
```

`Test::test1::test2` should allow me to write a proxy that can use `test1`, `test2` and `*args`.

How can I go about implementing this idea?

EDIT: I solved 2nd level but is there any methodology that could get me an unlimited number of levels?

Comment: What is a "ghost method"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Its a method received through method_missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
module Test
    def self.method_missing(name, *args)
        m = Module.new
        m.instance_variable_set("@name", name)
        def m.method_missing(name1, *args)
            puts @name
            puts name1
        end
        m
    end
end

Test::test1::test2
#Output:
#  test1
#  test2
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `Test::test1::test2` over `Test::test2`? A minor thing (that you probably know): you may omit `method_missing`'s second argument (`*args`) if you're not using it.